# Change settings on all Windows Forms forms

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config

I have changed my `app.config` file to allow the user to change the color scheme of the program. I can figure out how to change the background color of the form they are on where they change these settings:

```
Color colBackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.basicBackground;
this.BackColor = colBackColor;
```

But how can I change all of my forms background color? It's like I still want to pass all my forms to a function. I already asked that question and someone told me to use the `app.config` file. Now that I have done that, am I using it wrong?

Comment: Put that code in all the forms? Have a base form as suggested by King King. Use an interface, pass in color from your "main" form when you instantiate the others, use the Forms collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simply that you need a base form from which all your forms in your project **have to** inherit:

```
public class FormBase : Form {
   protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e){
    Color colBackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.basicBackground;
    BackColor = colBackColor;
   }
}
//Then all other forms have to inherit from that FormBase instead of the standard Form
public class Form1 : FormBase {
  //...
}
public class Form2 : FormBase {
  //...
}
```

### UPDATE

```
public interface INotifyChangeStyle {
   void ChangeStyle();
}    
public class FormBase : Form, INotifyChangeStyle {
   protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e){
      ChangeStyle();
   }
   public void ChangeStyle(){
      //Perform style changing here
      Color colBackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.basicBackground;
      BackColor = colBackColor;
      //--------
      foreach(var c in Controls.OfType<INotifyChangeStyle>()){
         c.ChangeStyle();
      }
   }
}
public class MyButton : Button, INotifyChangeStyle {
   public void ChangeStyle(){
      //Perform style changing here
      //....
      //--------
      foreach(var c in Controls.OfType<INotifyChangeStyle>()){
         c.ChangeStyle();
      }
   }
}
//...   the same for other control classes
```

Comment: ok, and if i have a group box or buttons and things on my base form and change the color, does that mean all my buttons and group boxes on other forms will have to inherit from those buttons and boxes?  i would like to change many things, the backcolor is just an example

Comment: @user2070677 that case is fairly **complex**, I think you may have to define some *interface*, all your controls you use in your project should implement, then you have to determine **when** we need to perform the **theme changing**, trigger on the form and it will spread on all the child controls.

Comment: this has shown me a lot.  its not quite there, as callingthe function onload is automatically changing the background when i run the program.  i want them to be able to select a color scheme in the program and have it change at that point.  but thanks a lot.  this has helped.  i havent used interfaces before (newb) so this was a good lesson